# Combining Node backend and Jumpsuit frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, frontend, backend

I used to use Node for the backend and React for the frontend and had no server issues. Now that I've changed to [jumpsuit](https://github.com/jumpsuit/jumpsuit) in the frontend I'm getting a websocket error when trying to run the Node server.

More specifically, when I run the Node server it starts on the port but when I got to localhost:9000 the page is blank and the console has this error:

[image: Jumpsuit WebSocket error]

This is my node:

**Server.js**

```
(function() {
"use strict";

// Express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', parameterLimit: 1000, extended: true}));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));
app.get('/search', require('./routes/search.js'));

module.exports = app;

}());
```

**Serve.js**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

// Import 'app' from server.js
var server = require('./server.js')
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({noServer: true});

// Set port as either specified by command line or 9000
server.set('port', (process.argv[2] || 9000));

// Start server
server.listen(server.get('port'), () => {
console.log(`Server started: http://localhost:${server.get('port')}/`);
});
server.on('upgrade', wss.handleUpgrade);
}());
```

My **index.html** is nothing but the bare bones:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome to Jumpsuit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Individually I know they're both working. If I use the index.html and app.js and launch it with 'jumpsuit watch' then it works, or if I remove the `<script src="app.js"></script>` from the index.html and run Node then the page loads all fine, so separately the jumpsuit and Node parts work. But I'm just wondering how I combine them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. I'm not gonna mark this as the official answer since it didn't actually solve the problem, just circumvented it, but hopefully if someone else has this problem they can use this workaround until an actual fix comes to light.

The Jumpsuit dev said that the error was because hot state reloading (HSR) was trying to turn on, despite me not telling it to in my Node setup or anywhere. He said this:

> *I am pretty sure as long as the `HSR_WS` env variable isn’t set, HSR*
>   *should not even run:*
>
> *1. Make sure that env variable isn’t set*
>
> *2. Make sure you’re up to date on the latest version of Jumpsuit*

This was based off this following line of code in hsr.js render, which checks the HSR_WS environmenet variable:

https://github.com/jumpsuit/jumpsuit/blob/ead48fa7da220e3cad82925d94f8136285f413af/src/render.js#L36

I verified that the HSR_WS env variable wasn't set (it wasn't) and I upgraded from Jumpsuit 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 and tested it again, then from 1.1.0 to 1.3.2 (latest non-official release) and tested it again and both times it still didn't work.

So eventually I just manually opened that websocket connection on that port and left it running in another terminal in the background, then ran the Node server and it worked fine.

How I did that was to first globally install wscat:

```
npm install -g wscat
```

Then ran it on the WS port in question:

```
wscat -l 43944
```

Finally, I opened a new terminal and ran the node server in that. It launched and was now working @ localhost:9000

Hopefully if anyone else has this issue they can use this workaround for the time being :)